# Как обращаться к форме на чужом сайте?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть вебсайт, на котором можно получить статистику по сайтам. На сайте инпут в который нужно вставлять данные

```
<input name="url">
```

Инпут в кнопкой

```
<input name="proceed">
```

Текст:

```
<b style="color:red">
```

Выполняю это через tampermonkey. Делаю так:

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);

jq.addEventListener('load',function () {
  var result = [];
  var websiteName = $('input[name=url]').val();
  var styleRedEl = $('b[style*="color:red"]').text();
  result[websiteName]=styleRedEl;
  console.log ( result );
  var websitesArr = [ "ya.ru", "google.com", "ok.ru", "vk.com", "fb.com" ];
  var inputVal = $('input[name=url]').val();
  for (i=0; i<websitesArr.length; i++) {
      $('input[name=url]').val(websitesArr[i]);
      alert (websitesArr[i]);
      $('input[name=proceed]').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

Как решить проблему того, что страница обновляется только после того как цикл прошел по всем элементам массива и по очереди вставил их в форму и только **после** этого нажимает кнопку. Нужно чтобы кнопка нажималась сразу после вставки каждого элемента массива в инпут.

Comment: Во-первых, что это за кнопка в виде текстового поля? Во-вторых, почему вы думаете, что кнопка нажимается один раз? Приведите доказательства. Я уверен, что клик происходит как у вас и указано в коде - 5 раз, на каждой итерации цикла.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын 1) вопрос в том как оформлена кнопка не ко мне. я повторюсь - работаю с чужим сайтом. мой опыт позволяет мне делать кнопку из input, a, span, button, p и в принципе любого тега 2) доказательства простые. если убрать алерт в 4 строке с конца кода, то просто показывается сразу результат для **fb.com**, то есть последнего элемента массива, если оставить алер, то вставляется значение из массива в инпут, выводится алерт с этим элементом, потом вставляется следующий элемент из массива в инпут и выводится алерт со следующим элементом массива и тд, и только в конце обновляется страница

Comment: @ИванПшеницын и самое простое - я могу отличить перезагрузилась страница или нет))

Comment: Не понял. Если при нажатии кнопки отправляется форма и обновляется страница, то чего вы хотите от 5ти нажатий кнопки? Пять обновлений страницы?) Самый очевидный ответ - кнопка у вас нажимается пять раз, как и задумано. Но вы должны понимать, что js код еще выполняется, после того как кнопка нажата и до тех пор, пока страница не перезагрузится. Он у вас и выполняется. И нажимает кнопку несколько раз подряд. Повесьте слушатель $('form').on('submit', function(){console.log('whatever')}) и, я уверен, вы убедитесь, что так оно и есть.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын я хочу 5 нажатий страницы. хочу чтобы после первого обновления страницы я мог прочитать полученные значения, потом снова нажать на кнопку и снова прочить результат после обновления страницы и так 5 раз

Comment: Скрипт выполняется в контексте ТЕКУЩЕЙ страницы. Когда страница закрывается/обновляется - скрипт перестает существовать. На новой странице будет только копия стрипта, "родившаяся" заново и ничего не знающая о "прошлой жизни" своей старой версии. Если вы хотите передать это знание - используйте независимые от текущей страницы хранилища. localStorage браузера, например. Туда вы можете сохранить ключ, на котором остановились, а после обновления страницы взять его оттуда и продолжить с того же места. Туда же можно складывать результаты, т.к. они тоже умирают вместе со страницей.